# Multiple filter condition in Spark Filter method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to write multiple case in `filter()` method in spark using scala like, I have an Rdd of `cogroup`

```
(1,(CompactBuffer(1,john,23),CompactBuffer(1,john,24)).filter(x => (x._2._1 != x._2._2))//value not equal
(2,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(2,Arun,24)).filter(x => (x._2._1==null))//Second tuple first value is null
(3,(CompactBuffer(3,kumar,25),CompactBuffer()).filter(x => (x._2._2==null))//Second tuple second value is null


val a = source_primary_key.cogroup(destination_primary_key).filter(x => (x._2._1 != x._2._2))

val c=  a.map { y =>



    val key = y._1
    val value = y._2

    srcs = value._1.mkString(",")
    destt = value._2.mkString(",")



    if (srcs.equalsIgnoreCase(destt) == false) {
      srcmis :+= srcs
      destmis :+= destt
    }

    if (srcs == "") {
      extraindest :+= destt.mkString("")
    }

    if (destt == "") {
      extrainsrc :+= srcs.mkString("")
    }


}
```

How to store each condition in 3 different Array[String]

I tried like above but seems naive, is there anyway way we can do it efficiently ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: Need three `Array[String]` a, b ,c  `a` has difference between two tuples, `b` has Second tuple's first value is null and `c` has Second tuple's second value is null

Comment: you want to combine all of the filters into one? or you want to store a rdd into three rdds on different filterings?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, the rdd has three types of values like given in the question I want to capture all the 3 in 3 different Array[String] I tried like above in the updated question

Comment: @Vignesh, you must have got those comactBuffer after you groupBy. Can you share the code of groupBy and sample input data for groupBy?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, I got this using `cogroup` the code is in the question and the input for cogroup is like `source.map(rec.split(",")(0),rec).cogroup(destination.map(rec.split(",")(0),rec)`

Comment: your code is confusing. Do us one more favor. can you give some sample input data and expected output from that input?

Comment: source input data `{(1,(1,john,23)),(3,(3,kumar,25))}` destination input data `{(1,(1,john,24)),(2,(2,arun,24))}` `cogroup output` `{(1,(CompactBuffer(1,john,23),CompactBuffer(1,john,24)),(2,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(2,Arun,24)),(3,(CompactBuffer(3,kumar,25),CompactBuffer())}` Expected output is `(1,(CompactBuffer(1,john,23),CompactBuffer(1,john,24))` in separate `Array[String]` say a,  `(2,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(2,Arun,24)) in Array[String] b` and `(3,(CompactBuffer(3,kumar,25),CompactBuffer()) in separate Array[String] c` using `filter and map` statement

Comment: @Vignesh, I just answered below :) please check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing purpose, I created following `rdds`

```
val source_primary_key = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,(1,"john",23)),(3,(3,"kumar",25))))
val destination_primary_key = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,(1,"john",24)),(2,(2,"arun",24))))
```

Then I `cogrouped` as you did

```
val coGrouped = source_primary_key.cogroup(destination_primary_key)
```

Now is the step to `filter` the cogrouped `rdd` to three separate `rdds` as

```
val a = coGrouped.filter(x => !x._2._1.isEmpty && !x._2._2.isEmpty)
val b = coGrouped.filter(x => x._2._1.isEmpty && !x._2._2.isEmpty)
val c = coGrouped.filter(x => !x._2._1.isEmpty && x._2._2.isEmpty)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: my pleasure :) thanks for the acceptance and upvote :)

Answer (score -3):

You can use `collect` on your RDD and then `toList`  .
Example :

```
(1,(CompactBuffer(1,john,23),CompactBuffer(1,john,24)).filter(x => (x._2._1 != x._2._2)).collect().toList
```